# Need Help on Cookie-based Toggle Menu

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle

I've written a cookie-based toggle show/hide menu. It remembers what was open/closed using the jQuery cookie plugin. It exactly works fine; the only problem is I have to add different script for each menu. So each menu has its own script.

This is the code so far:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var panel = $("#f1_fold");
var button = $("#f1_fold_i");
var initialState = "expanded";
var activeClass = "hidden";
var visibleText = "<img src='html/sys-img/min.gif' alt='-' />";
var hiddenText = "<img src='html/sys-img/plus.gif' alt='+' />";


if($.cookie("panelState1") == undefined) {
    $.cookie("panelState1", initialState);
}
var state = $.cookie("panelState1");
if(state == "collapsed") {
    panel.hide();
    button.html(hiddenText);
    button.addClass(activeClass);
}

button.click(function(){
    if($.cookie("panelState1") == "expanded") {
        $.cookie("panelState1", "collapsed");
        button.html(hiddenText);
        button.addClass(activeClass);
    } else {
        $.cookie("panelState1", "expanded");
        button.html(visibleText);
        button.removeClass(activeClass);
    }
    panel.slideToggle("1000");
    return false;
});
});
```

And here is the HTML snippet

```
<div class="tableborder"> 
      <div class='maintitle'> 
      <div style='float: right; width: auto !important; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 3px;'><a id='f1_fold_i' id='1' href='#' style='vertical-align:middle; border:0px solid #000; cursor:pointer;' /><img src='html/sys-img/min.gif' alt='-' /></a></div> 
<div><img src='style_images/1/nav_m.gif' border='0'  alt='&gt;' width='8' height='8' />&nbsp;<a href="index.php?c=1">Gotei 13</a></div> 
</div> 
      <span id='f1_fold' style='display:;'> 
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">  
        <tr>
          <th align="left" colspan="2" width="59%" class='titlemedium'>Forum</th> 
          <th align="right" width="14%" class='titlemedium'>Stats</th> 
          <th align="left" width="25%" class='titlemedium'>Last Post Info</th> 
        </tr> 
<tr> 
          <td class="row4" align="center"><img src='subnonew.gif' border='0'  alt='No New Posts' /></td>   
          <td class="row4"><b class="dtitle"><a href="index.php?showforum=1">Rules &amp; Announcement Board</a></b><br /><span class="desc">Pengumuman, panduan, dan peraturan forum dipajang di sini. Baru daftar? Yuk tengok dulu sebelum posting~<br /></span></td> 
          <td class="row2" align="right">58 Topics <br />1410 Replies</td> 
          <td class="row2" nowrap="nowrap"> 
<a href='index.php?showtopic=2069&amp;view=getlastpost' title='Go to last post'><img src='http://209.85.62.23/style_images/1/lastpost.gif' border='0'  alt='Last Post' /></a> 
Today at 01:59 am<br />In:&nbsp;<a href='index.php?showtopic=2069&amp;view=getnewpost' title='[INFO] Gelar Jepang UI 2011 (Go to first unread)'>[INFO] Gelar Jepang UI 2011</a><br />By: <a href='index.php?showuser=1'>Xaliber</a> <br />Thread: <a href='index.php?showforum=36'>Gathering &amp; Events</a></td> 
        </tr> </table></span><table width="100%"><tr> 
          <td class='darkrow2' colspan="5">&nbsp;</td> 
        </tr> 
      </table> 

    </div>
```

Notice that I have to add different script for each menu because it depends on the `f1_fold` and `f1_fold_i` css ID. For the other menu, it would be `f2_fold` and `f2_fold_i`. For the other, it'd be `f3_fold` and `f3_fold_i`. Etc.

Also, to make the cookie remembers which menu is collapsed and which menu is opened, it also depends on the `panelState1` (for 1st menu), `panelState2` (for the 2nd), `panelState3`, etc

Is there any way to make this shorter and more flexible? So I don't have to add different variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a year, though not achieving exactly what I meant, I found that using the [collapsible jQuery plugin](http://blog.ramin-hossaini.com/2010/04/27/jquery-collapsible-plugin/) is more practical.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap each menu in a div with a class of 'menuWrapper' (or something similar) and then used [jQuery's 'each' function](http://api.jquery.com/each/), you could execute a function on each of your menus. Change your 'xf_fold' and 'xf_fold_i' ids to 'f_fold' and 'f_fold_i' classes. Then, in the function that runs on each menu item, you can select them based on class. Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8rZR/) could do the trick.

#### Update

Here's [a new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/5f8u9/) demonstrating a cookie based selected item remembering solution.

Comment: Thanks... but I can't get it to save/remember the state, which menu is collapsed and which menu is opened...

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. If you can guarantee the order of the menus in the html, you could do `$('.menuWrapper')[menuIndexThatIsStoredInACookie]` to get the menu item that was open. Alternatively, go back to having a number in an id and do something like `$('#menu_'+menuIndexThatIsStoredInACookie)` to select the previously open menu item. Is that the kind of thing that you are after?

Comment: Sorry, just got back from the hospital...

Yes, apparently, it is very close to what I mean, but I still cannot get what you mean (perhaps because of my poor English, I apologize). So where do the scripts obtain the cookie information, following your example from the fiddle?

Comment: I've created a [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/5f8u9/) that may be a bit clearer? It stores the id of the selected menu item in a cookie and retrieves it on load. Does that make sense? Let me know if you need me to elaborate.

Comment: Oh, I get it now... sorry for the extra-late reply.

Comment: No worries. Does this do what you want?

Comment: Odd... my comment seem to disappear? That was supposed to be longer.. I'll try to rewrite it then: hmm... it's not precisely what I meant though, as it is more similar to accordion script? What I meant is something like collapse-and-hide category... something you could see on forum boards, like this one: http://community.invisionpower.com/ (notice the "plus" and "min" on each categories)